# Removing item from array based on id

Tags: javascript

I have two array's. One of id's of elements that I need to show and then another of the elements in a drop down. If the id's match then then show. It sounds simple, but I'm having trouble slicing out the elements that do not need to show.

So it kind of looks like this

```
var option = //Ton of objects with values that match with the id that look like this, there are about 70 of them. I need to loop through these to get the value of each one. Please see screen shot, I don't know how else to show that they are objects.
```

[image]
    var ids = [16, 15, 17, 18, 5];

and then I was trying to loop through each option and see if the value is equal to the Id. For some reason this is removing everything instead of just the once that need to be removed.

```
for(var i=0 ; i<option.length; i++){
    if (option[i].value !== ids) { 
        option.splice(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: `ids.indexOf(option[i].value)`

Comment: jQuery does all things -> `$('option:eq(' + ids.join('), option:eq(') + ')').remove();`

Comment: note that `1 !== [1,2]` and `3 !== [1,2]` are both true.  I'm guessing that `option[i].value !== ids` is always true.

Comment: option is clearly not an array as I found out. It's an object containing other objects. This makes it almost impossible to help you. Just do a `console.log(JSON.stringify(option))` and post that.

Comment: @Mouser I said they were objects in an array from the beginning! "Ton of objects with values that match with the id" And a stringify does nothing buy turn it into a string....that's not what I need to do.

Comment: @zazvorniki I know that stringify turns it into a string. That was my whole idea. Post that string in your question so we can see the structure of the option object.

Comment: @zazvorniki One question really comes to mind. Are you understanding what you are implementing? Most answers here provide a really good approach, but just need to be tweaked a little to match your option object.

Answer (score 2):

Try out the filter function:

```
var newOptions = options.filter(function(option, index) {
     return ids.indexOf(option.value) >= 0;
});

var values = newOptions.map(function(option) {
    return option.value;
});
```

Comment: Inside my for? And does it have to be a var?

Comment: In my example I've renamed your array of options from 'option' to 'options'. The example replaces the for loop and creates a new array newOptions that contains only the options with 'values' inside the 'ids' array. This has to have var since it is the declaration of a new array.

Comment: I need to be able to loop trough each option because they are objects (70 of them) with multiple things attached to them and I only need the value.  I can't set it to a varable

Comment: The filter function does the looping. It calls the function argument for every element of options.

If you wish to transform the filtered options into their values after filtering for the match use the 'map' function as I will demonstrate above.

Comment: Edited my answer to include a demo of map. 'values' array will contain only the values that are found in the options where the value exists in the array of ids.

Comment: This just broke all my other code on the page. I am trying to just omit options in a select tag hence the slice.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove items from the `option` array:

```js
var option = [
    {display:'opt50', value:50 },
    {display:'opt16', value:16 },
    {display:'opt10', value:10 },
    {display:'opt17', value:17 },
    {display:'opt43', value:43 },
    {display:'opt5', value:5 }
]


var ids = [16, 15, 17, 18, 5];

for(var i = option.length - 1; i > -1; i--) {
    if(ids.indexOf(option[i].value) == -1) {
        option.splice(i,1);
    }
}

// logs [{"display":"opt16","value":16},{"display":"opt17","value":17},{"display":"opt5","value":5}]
console.dir(JSON.stringify(option));
```

If you want to just find matching items and keep `option` intact:

```js
// fill in options with some elements
var option = [
    {display:'opt50', value:50 },
    {display:'opt16', value:16 },
    {display:'opt10', value:10 },
    {display:'opt17', value:17 },
    {display:'opt43', value:43 },
    {display:'opt5', value:5 }
]


var ids = [16, 15, 17, 18, 5];

var filteredOption = option.filter(function(o) {
    return ids.indexOf(o.value) > -1;
});

// logs [{"display":"opt16","value":16},{"display":"opt17","value":17},{"display":"opt5","value":5}]
console.dir(JSON.stringify(filteredOption));
```

Answer (score -1):

The `!==` operator is always going to return true.

```
12 !== [12,34,45]
true
13 !== [12,34,45]
true
```

As a result, `if (option[i].value !== ids) {` will always execute `option.splice(i);` since the compared values are always *different types*.

[Mozilla's Sameness documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Sameness) has a great explanation and useful chart.

Comment: Yeah, I tried this. It didn't remove anything from the list.

Comment: That was why I was asking my question. I know what I was doing was wrong, I just don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Why -1?  This explains the issue of why, "For some reason this is removing everything"

Answer (score -1):

```js
    var option = [{display: "Member Form",value: 2}, {display: "Member Form",value: 5}];

    var ids = [16, 15, 17, 18, 5];
    var optionKey = Object.keys(option);
    for(var i = optionKey.length - 1; i >= 0 ; i--){
       if (ids.indexOf(option[optionKey[i]].value) == -1) { 
           option.splice(i, 1) //second argument allows splice to only delete one element.
       }
    }
    console.log(option);
    document.write(JSON.stringify(option)); //result!
```

Comment: @zazvorniki, updated it, should work. If not your option array is in a different format.

Comment: My options do not look like that at all though. If you see in my initial post I stated that they are objects in an array. So, this does not work...

Comment: @zazvorniki this is it. If not try to edit it out so it corresponds with the structure of your option Object. Because you didn't provide us with a clear example of it, so we're guessing in the dark.

Comment: I just posted a screen show of what the objects look like. Each has a value in it.

Comment: Why am I voted down. This script does exactly what needs to be done?